# When flying between Airport Mataveri (IPC) and Santiago International Airport (SCL), do customs throw away some food/plants upon arrival?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, chile, easter-island, ipc

When flying between [Mataveri International Airport (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mataveri_International_Airport) in [Easter Island, Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island) and [Santiago International Airport (SCL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arturo_Merino_Ben%C3%ADtez_International_Airport),  do customs throw away some types of food/plants upon arrival?

Since both airports are in the same country, I would tend to think no, but since Easter Island is located quite remotely from the rest of Chile, I would tend to think yes. I couldn't find the information easily online.

Comment: Being the same country does not mean much. USA and Australia have different zones, you can not bring plants across the borders between those zones. I do not know for Chile, but why try? Easier not to bring food or plants.

Comment: @Willeke I agree, I would also bet we cannot (just like we can't between Hawaii and US mainland), but I'm unfamiliar with Easter island. Why try? Because 1) I don't want to throw away food 2) shop for decently healthy food at night (maybe all shops are closed, especially on Easter Island, and I'd prefer to limit how often to frequent shops)